# Describe Autoscaling group reading a Variable

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to set variable stackname=Teststack

When I run the below command Its reading the curly bracket also.

{'$stackname'} is returned as {Teststack} where I just want Teststack without the curly brackets.

Command:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, {'$stackname'})].[AutoScalingGroupName]'
```

Error:

```
Bad value for --query AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, {Teststack})].[AutoScalingGroupName]:
  Expecting: colon, got: rbrace: Parse error at column 85, token "}" (RBRACE), for expression:
  "AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, {Teststack})].[AutoScalingGroupName]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you have a variable `$stackname` that contains the name of your stack, and you want to return the `AutoScalingGroupName` field for the auto-scaling group that is tagged with that stack name.

Because that is what the query you wrote is trying to do.

If so, you can do that using this query:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
  --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, `'$teststack'`)].AutoScalingGroupName' \
  --output text
```